# symfony2: trying to render a form in the template

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to render a form that I've just generated from an entity, but Im getting the error below...

```
<?php

namespace Prueba\FrontendBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Prueba\FrontendBundle\Form\ItemType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
* @Route("/hello")
* @Template()          
*/                      
public function indexAction($name)       
{                              
     $form = new ItemType();var_dump(get_class($form));                                 
                return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(             
                                        'form' => $form->createView(),
                                                 ));
    }                            
}
```

> string(35) "Prueba\FrontendBundle\Form\ItemType" Fatal error: Call to
>   undefined method Prueba\FrontendBundle\Form\ItemType::createView() in
>   /home/javier/programacion/sf2000/src/Prueba/FrontendBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
>   on line 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$form = new ItemType();
```

to

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType());
```

And if you want to attach an empty entity to the form (easier validation and form processing):

```
$item = new Item();
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $item);
```